# Is there a shorter way of specifying which class to run?

Tags: php, class

Normally, I would have to do:

```
$str = "classname"; //classname is the name of a class

switch($str)
{
  case "class1":
    class1::run(); break;
  case "class2":
    class2::run(); break;
  case "class3":
    class3::run(); break;
  case "class4":
    class4::run(); break;
  case "classname":
    classname::run(); break;
  default:
    die("Fatal error: no such class");
}
//in my case, there are hundreds of cases and more being added
```

Is there a way of simplifying this, perhaps in one line? Wishful thinking?

```
$str::run()
```

Of course, it would be my responsibility to make sure $str is actually the name of an object. But managing that would be much easier than managing a huge list like above.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; as you guessed, `$str::run();` works.

```
php> class A { public static function run() { echo "A!"; } }

php> class B { public static function run() { echo "B!"; } }

php> $n = "A";

php> $n::run();
A!
php> $n = "B";

php> $n::run();
B!
```

Comment: Odd, it does not work for me: http://ideone.com/9iLvP maybe ideone uses an outdated version of php?

Comment: I guess it's version-dependent, then. I'm running PHP 5.3.8; ideone appears to be using 5.2.12.

Comment: Yeah; it looks like it was added in PHP 5.3.0: ["Added support for dynamic access of static members using `$foo::myFunc()`. (Etienne Kneuss)"](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
if (class_exists($str) && method_exists($str,'run')){
  {$tr}::run();
}
```